# Why doesn't UPX work for .NET executables?

Tags: .net, compression, executable, portable-executable

If .NET executables are PE Files, why all packers like UPX "corrupts" it?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the "[Ultimate Packer for Executables](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)" when you are using the "UPX" acronym?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPX is designed for *native* applications. These are applications that compile directly to machine code.

Executables that target the .NET Framework are not native applications, but rather *managed* ones. In other words, they run on top of a runtime enviroment (the Common Language Runtime, or CLR) and are compiled to an "intermediate language" (IL) that is not compiled into machine language until runtime (this process is known as JIT, or just-in-time, compilation).

UPX can deal directly with unmanaged machine code, but it doesn't work for managed applications. How is the JIT compiler going to compile the application's code on-the-fly if it's compressed and therefore unreadable? It won't; it's going to see the file as corrupted.

No big loss, though. There are more disadvantages today to compressing an executable than there are advantages. And besides that, since managed applications are compiled to IL, they are often smaller than the equivalent unmanaged application in the first place.

Comment: But you don't explain why managed instructions can't be handled by UPX too. I am sure there is a reason, but you don't mention it. "How is the CPU going to run the native code if it's compressed and therefore unreadable? It won't; it's going to see the file as corrupted." is almost as good an argument as to why UPX can not compress x86 binaries. For instance, it could put a real EXE around the IL EXE and uncompress the IL EXE to another file, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX

Comment: I thought I covered that. UPX deals directly with unmanaged code. It does the decoding, so it works. It doesn't work for JIT-compiled applications because UPX isn't designed to uncompress the code in advance and feed it to the JIT compiler. Yes, I don't suppose there is any technical reason why you couldn't write a packer for JIT-compiled applications. But, at least when I wrote this answer, UPX was not.

Comment: "There are more disadvantages today to compressing an executable than there are advantages"